# powershell returned an error:(403) WebException using New-pnpList

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I had my PS script running the other day and created a new list with a single field with no issues.  Was able to view the list in the Site Contents lib.

Today, it's not working.  I tried running the PS code below and then resorted to running the new-pnplist code at the command line...got the same error which is shown below.

I'm using the Global admin account.  Using version 3.13.19 SharePointPNPPowerShellOnline.  Executed the commands from Powershell ISE which is what I did the other day when it worked.  And, I was able to connect successfully using the Connect-sposervice command.

Error:

```
new-pnplist -Template GenericList -Title 'TestPNP2'
new-pnplist : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
At line:1 char:1
+ new-pnplist -Template GenericList -Title $ListName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [New-PnPList], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.NewList
```

Code:

```
$TargetListURL="https://<my sharepoint.com>/sites/CKCDemo"
$ListName="TESTPNP2"

Connect-PnPOnline -url $TargetListURL -CurrentCredentials
New-PnPList -Template GenericList -Title $ListName
Add-PnPField -List $ListName -DisplayName "MyTEST" -InternalName "MyTEST" -Type Text -AddToDefaultView
Get-PnPList`
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enough permission to create a list in this site. You could try to go to the site directly, check whether you could create a list through ui.

Note: A global admin will not automatically have access to individual sites unless explicitly granted.